# Installing openCPU with exotic path to Apache

Tags: apache, opencpu

I am installing OpenCPU on a production RedHat 7 Server and it turned out that the path to their Apache server is not

```
/etc/httpd
```

but something else.
Apparently, OpenCPU was still referring to /etc/httpd and therefore did not work.
I am wondering if there is a way to specify custom path to Apache server for OpenCPU installation (as a parameter for installation, or somewhere in the code, or after installation)?

OpenCPU version is 2.0.7, RedHat version is 7.3, Apache server version is 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your Apache2 located then? Did you compile it from source?

OpenCPU depends on `httpd` via [rapache](https://github.com/jeffreyhorner/rapache/blob/master/rpm/rapache.spec) (which has `mod_R`). The [rApache manual](http://rapache.net/manual.html) has some docs about how to compile rapache from source against a custom version of R or Apache.

Once this works you can try to build OpenCPU. The default opencpu-server [rpm spec](https://github.com/opencpu/opencpu-server/blob/master/rpm/opencpu.spec) is copies [opencpu.conf](https://github.com/opencpu/opencpu-server/blob/master/opencpu-server/sites-available/opencpu.conf) into `/etc/httpd` because that is the path of the `httpd` package in Fedora or Enterprise Linux. I guess you could modify that if you run a non-standard version of httpd.

Comment: The apache server is installed by the admins, I don't really know what they did, they just gave me the path and they refuse to move it.

Thanks for the info, I will look into rApache manual and try reinstalling it. 
And in the OpenCPU spec file, do I understand correctly that I should only change paths in lines 77, 86, and 131?

Comment: You can also try to install the rpm package as-is and manually copy `opencpu.conf` file to your local apache directory.